# I am using google API in a page on wordpress and it is not working, it shows a blank page

Tags: wordpress

I have an edited code of google API. It is not working on the page on wordpress. I have entered the code in text box but it shows a blank page

Comment: You know there's no possible way anyone could help you with this, based on what you've asked, right? What's the code? Which (of the dozens available) Google APIs are you working with? What are you trying to make the code do?

Comment: @Greg Burkett.
Kindly see the code in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
@Greg Burkett


<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['geochart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Province', 'popularity'],
          ['Federally Administered Tribal Areas',100],
          ['Islamabad',1000],
          ['Punjab',800],
          ['PK-KP',500], // North West Frontier
          ['Azad Kashmir',300],
          ['PK-GB',150], // Northern Areas
          ['Baluchistan',600],
          ['Sind',100]
        ]);

        var options = {
          region: 'PK',
          backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
          datalessRegionColor: 'white',
          width: 1170,
          height: 695,
          resolution: 'provinces',
          colors: ['#FC0000','#FF3333','#FFFF00','#00FF00','#0CFF0C']
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="regions_div" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```